# Excel - Several columns with and without data

Tags: excel, organized

My spreadsheet has 20 x 100.000 (columns x lines) of data but with several empty columns, it was obtained from a PDF report. I would like to "group" all columns, therefore removing empty spaces in between, preferably without VBA codes. See example below.

Original spreadsheet:

```
Col.1 | Col.2 | Col.3 | Col.4 | Col.5    
12345 | empty | ABCD  | empty | 1A2B    
empty | empty | 45678 | empty | x1z2
```

Desired result:

```
Col.1 | Col.2 | Col.3 | Col.4 | Col.5 |  
12345 | ABCD  | 1A2B  | empty | empty |    
45678 | x1z2  | empty | empty | empty |
```

Comment: Programming is a difficult task and we have to use available tools. In this case, VBA was not an option and, even though, a solution was possible. Thanks Scott Craner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Highlight the entire range.

[image]

2. Go to Find & Select from the `HOME` tab.
3. Choose `Go To Special`.
4. Choose `Blanks` and hit `OK`.

[image]

Result:

[image]

5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>.
6. Choose `Shift cells left` and hit `OK`.

[image]

Result:

[image]